# tslint-disable comment in method chains

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint, typescript-eslint

I am populating an Array and using it to map onto a sequence of React components

```
    return (
        <div className={style}>
            <Header title="INVENTORY" />
            {Array(slots)
                .fill(0)
                .map((_, i) => (
                    <ItemSlot />
                ))}
        </div>
    )
```

this line `.map((_, i) => (` shows warnings

```
'_' is defined but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

```
'i' is defined but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I attempt to add the `/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */` comment, but it doesn't seem to work anywhere I've tried to put it. For example

```
                .fill(0) /* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
                .map((_, i) => (
                    <ItemSlot />
                ))}
```

has no effect.

How can I add tslint comment overrides on methods being chained?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using the variables you can just omit them:

```
Array(slots)
  .fill(0)
  .map(() => (
    <ItemSlot />
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your question.

First off - you've got your tools mixed up. `tslint` is one tool and `eslint` is another. The errors you've listed are coming from `eslint`, not `tslint`.

Because you've got your wires crossed - you're attempting to use a tslint disable comment instead of an eslint disable comment. ESLint disables look like

```
// eslint-disable-next-line <name of rule>
// eslint-disable-line <name of rule>
```

i.e.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-var
// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-var
```

Next - as John mentioned in his answer - if you're not using any of the arguments - then there's no need to declare them at all - you can (and should) just omit them entirely as they are unnecessary cruft.

Finally - if you want the rule to ignore underscore named arguments, you can use the `argsIgnorePattern` option, eg:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
```